# Capture a section of screen including active menu and cursor in Centos

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, centos, screen-capture

I am using centos release 6.7 (Final). I would like to capture a section of screen including active menu and cursor for making turorial as in the picture below.

Could anyone tell me how to do that? 
What software should I install?

Or is there any keyboard shortcut?

Thank you.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I've been using [shutter](http://shutter-project.org/) for this task. It is easy to setup and use.

In order to install Shutter you can use the following commands:

```
sudo yum install epel-release
sudo rpm -Uvh http://li.nux.ro/download/nux/dextop/el6/x86_64/nux-dextop-release-0-1.el6.nux.noarch.rpm 
sudo yum install shutter
```